# Custom cluster groups in Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast, ignite

For my summer internship project, I am trying to distribute a job over multiple nodes. However i want to programatically create custom cluster groups based on a predicate (cpu usage), like in Apache Ignite. My company already uses Hazelcast IMDG. Does Hazelcast offer similar functionality? I know i can create different Hazelcast instances based on the group name, but is there a way to use cpu metrics to create custom cluster groups in Hazelcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you mentioned in Ignite doesn't create a cluster but return the members that matched the given condition. You can use `MemberSelector` in Hazelcast to do something similar. The only limitation is you need to pre-define those attributes, or you need to have a scheduled task running on all members that updates those attributes so you can again use them.

Please check this: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#defining-member-attributes